# Dynamic fields in cq:dialog based on page in aem 6.5 using component specific clientlibs

Tags: aem-6

I have a component that contains many text fields and dropdowns and it is being used in many pages, now only one of those fields much be shown in each page and all the remaining must be hidden depending on the current page. Is there anyway to do it with component specific clientlibs js

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs allow for a property called `extraClientLibs` you can write your custom client library and add it to your dialog.  Listen to the `dialog-ready` ready event and use that logic to capture and hide/show whatever fields you need.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. But can I know how to access the resource page path (content path of page) in which this component is being used. so that I can show hide the fields based on the page.

Comment: There is an OOTB method `Granite.author.getPageInfoLocation()` that will return the path of the current page for you.